# rvalue reference в параметре

Tags: c++, функции, rvalue

```
void h(const int& n) {//тут эрвелью
    cout << "copy\n";
}

void h(int&& n) {//тут эрвелью и какую выбрать?
    cout << "move\n";
}

int main() {

    int y = 0;
    h(y);
    h(9);}
```

Вопрос: если константная rvalue ссылка может принимать как rvalue, так и lvalue, по какому принципу тогда выбирается функция для rvalue? Есть что ли какой-то приоритет выбора? И почему еще после std::move() обязательно идет в rvalue-ref если она и в const lvalue reference также может?

Comment: Тут особо нечего объяснять, вы и сами все видите. У rvalue-ссылок приоритет при передаче rvalue.

Comment: В первой функции тип параметра не r-value. А ранжирование функций-кандидатов описано в стандарте.

Answer (score 3):

Для обычных объектов вы можете сделать четыре декларации функций. И на каждый тип будет отдельная функция. Если какого-то вида не написали, будет выполнен другой, в зависимости от приоритетов.

Вот граф. Начинать искать надо от входного типа, и спускаться ниже для поиска функции с максимальным приоритетом.

```
     &
   /   \
C &     \
   \     \ 
    \    V &
     \  /
    C V &
```

*C - **const***
*V - **volatile***

Пример :

```cpp
int fun ( int & ) ;
int fun ( int const & ) ;
int main(){
  int x ;
  fun ( x ) ;
}
```

Будет вызван `int fun ( int & ) ;` так как у него выше приоритет чем у `int fun ( int const & ) ;`.

*Если добавить декларацию функции, принимающую по значению, то она будет конфликтовать неоднозначностью с `T &&`, `T const &&` и `T const &`. Лучше выбирать тип ссылки.*

---

r-value объект также может быть принят l-value константной ссылкой. И граф выбора функций будет такой :

```
           &&
         /    \
     C &&      \
      /  \      \ 
     /    \      V &&
    /      \   /
   /       C V &&
  /
C &
```

*C - **const***
*V - **volatile***